# How do you write a regular expression that will match one, two or three capture groups

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression that is flexible enough to match on one, two, or three capture groups. Unfortunately, I am only able to match two or three capture groups. In the image below the item highlighted in yellow remains unmatched. I would expect it to match **AB**. My sample data and regular expression are located here: [Sample Data and regular expresion](https://regex101.com/r/k38MRt/1/)

[image]

In words, I'm trying to match 1, 2, or 3 capture groups of alpha charters that are surrounded by 1s or 0s.

Comment: Like this? `[01]([A-Z]+)(?=[01]|$)(?:.*?[01]([A-Z]+)(?=[01]|$)(?:.*?[01]([A-Z]+)(?=[01]|$))?)?`  https://regex101.com/r/Ujt75H/1

Answer (score 0):

Using `\d` can match more than 0 or 1 only, and using `\d?` means an optional digit.

As there seems to be a digit always to the left, and at the right there can be either 0 or 1 or the end of the string, you can assert the right part instead of matching it.

The pattern matches:

```
[01]([A-Z]+)(?=[01]|$)(?:.*?[01]([A-Z]+)(?=[01]|$)(?:.*?[01]([A-Z]+)(?=[01]|$))?)?
```

- `[01]` Match either 0 or 1
- `([A-Z]+)(?=[01]|$)` Capture **group 1**, match 1+ chars A-Z and assert either `0` or `1` or the end of the string to the right.
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `.*?[01]([A-Z]+)(?=[01]|$)` Match as least amount of chars till next next occurrence for **group 2**
  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `.*?[01]([A-Z]+)(?=[01]|$)` Match as least amount of chars till next next occurrence for **group 3**
  - `)?` Close group and make it optional
- `)?` Close group and make it optional

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5gylwq/1)